# How to do filter on specified controller action in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have CartController route filter seems only can bind on controller or get, can I do the auth filter on "action"?

for example:

```
<?php

CartController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex() {
        // not need filter
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        // not need filter
    }

    public function getCheck()
    {
        // need to filter
    }

}
```

Comment: just add the filter in routes.... laravel3 or 4 is same here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the BaseController beforeFilter() Action in your Class constructor and pass the Actions you want filtered as an 'only' keyed Array as the second Argument.

```
$this->beforeFilter('filtername', 
                    array('only' => array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
```

Using your example code:

```
<?php

CartController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->beforeFilter('filtername', array('only' =>
                            array('getCheck')));
    }

    public function getIndex() {
        // not need filter
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        // not need filter
    }

    public function getCheck()
    {
        // need to filter
    }

}
```

Source: [Laravel Docs: Controller Filter](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to mix RESTful and normal methods (get/post vs action) together in the same controller, and at least in Laravel 3 this couldn't be done.

For filtering, you can look into [controller filters](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters) where you can specific the auth filter for specific methods or go the other way and exclude certain methods from the filter.

Comment: Is that mean I can only do it in route, or have to write the filter logic by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the filter in the method you need it in.

See the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters) to see what that looks like in code.

```
 $this->beforeFilter('my-filter-name');
```

Comment: But I want to do it in functions under class, it seems can only setting in class

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a resource controller and was able to do this:

```
$this->beforeFilter('admin', [ 'except' => ['index','show'] ]);
```